# Change color and position of CircularProgress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use CircularProgress provided by Material.

I created this component in order to change its color:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';

class ColoredCircularProgress extends Component {
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return <CircularProgress {...this.props} classes={{colorPrimary: classes.colorPrimary}}/>;
}
}

const styles = props => ({
    colorPrimary: {
        backgroundColor: '#FD8907',
    }
});

export default  withStyles(styles)(ColoredCircularProgress);
```

However on my site it looks like this:

[image]

My questions are :

1. I want the circle to look orange and instead the circle looks still blue and it adds a square orange box behind.
2. It also displays at the top left corner of my site. How can I place it right in the center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the style  by applying css on `.MuiCircularProgress-colorPrimary` class.

Try this, hope this will work.

**Example**

```
.MuiCircularProgress-colorPrimary {
    color: green !important;
}

.MuiCircularProgress-root { 
    left: 43%; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 44vh; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked and changed the color the way I wanted. Do you know how I can center the circle in my html?

Comment: Use this css to center. `.MuiCircularProgress-root {
    left: 43%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44vh;
}`

Answer (score 25):

To change the color you can simple do this:

```html
<CircularProgress style={{'color': 'yellow'}}/>
```

It works for Material-UI v4.x (I didn't try with minor versions)

Comment: Works for v5 too

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to override css.

Here's my solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';

const defaultSize = 50;

class ColoredCircularProgressComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes, size } = this.props;
    return <CircularProgress {...this.props} classes={classes} size={size} />;
  }
}

class ColoredCircularProgress extends Component {
  render() {
    const WithStylesComponent = withStyles(theme => ({
      colorPrimary: {
        color: this.props.foreColor
      },
      root: {
        top: `calc(50% - ${this.props.size / 2}px)`,
        left: `calc(50% - ${this.props.size / 2}px)`,
        position: 'absolute'
      }
    }))(ColoredCircularProgressComponent);
    return <WithStylesComponent {...this.props} />;
  }
}

ColoredCircularProgress.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object,
  size: PropTypes.number,
  foreColor: PropTypes.string
};
ColoredCircularProgress.defaultProps = {
  size: defaultSize,
  foreColor: 'green'
};

export default ColoredCircularProgress;
```

Comment: I wrapped the original component to accept size and to put the component exactly the center of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the overrides in your theme. To make the color change globally.

```
    MuiCircularProgress:{circle:{color:"green"},}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!